# iPad specific resource suffix doesn't work with storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, ios-universal-app

According to the [Apple's Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2) you should be able to use device modifiers for any kind of resource file

Here's the quote

> You can apply device modifiers to any type of resource file.

However while this seems to work for most resources (images, nibs) I'm running into problems when using it with storyboards.

What I've tried doing is having two storyboards with one of them having the `~ipad` suffix attached to it's file name, and trying to load it like the following

```
  UIStoryboard *mySB = 
       [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    myViewController = [sigRequestSB instantiateInitialViewController];
```

And I'm getting a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception

The strange thing is that I only get this error if I have a storyboard with the `~ipad` modifier, if I have only the single storyboard without the modifier it will just load that on the iPad. Further if I detect the what device is running and load the storyboard using the full file name (that is on an iPad attach the "~ipad" to the filename) it works.

Here's the full error

> 2013-08-29 15:32:44.294 MyApp[18757:c07] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could
>   not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle 
>   (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-Cq1-k2-VhC' and directory
>   'MyStoryboard.storyboardc''

Comment: Looks like it's a known and still open issue. See [rdar://12753707](http://openradar.appspot.com/12753707) and possibly dupe it.

Comment: @iHunter that does seem to be the same issue that I have, though it doesn't mention that it seems like iOS sort of recognizes the modifier since I get the exception while if there weren't a second storyboard it would just load he iPhone one. As for dupes I did spend some time searching and I found similar issues loading storyboards or nibs in code but not that it works for all resources except for storyboards.